Is it okay to kneel to propose to a woman?
I usually try to be very careful when kneeling down for things as I know the LORD only wants us to worship him and him alone.
Now I love this woman I have been in a relationship with. I would like to propose to her.. and I know many people get down on one knee to propose.. but I'm not sure if I'm overthinking it but would it be wrong to do so?
Is kneeling only for when worshiping the living GOD?
Please advise.

As worded, this sounds like it's asking for personal advice, which is not appropriate on this site, and might be closed or removed for that reason. It would be better received if it were reworded to be an objective impersonal question (e.g. remove all 8 instances of "I").

I've never heard of any Christians say that any kneeling means you're worshipping. That's not remotely a Christian teaching.

Even if you were to prostrate yourself - that would be ok so long as you aren’t treating her as some kind of a god(dess). Moses prostrated himself before his Father in law (and is the same word otherwise translated as “worship”). Nothing wrong with “worshipping” = “honoring” another human being; but we are to serve God alone.

@RyanPierceWilliams Sounds like the beginning if an answer, care to post an answer?

Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

Many in the past kneeled on one knee to royalty and only on two knees to Deity. But if the 'man is the head of the woman' (in the church) then why would one be kneeling in the first place ?

@NigelJ, I agree with you. Only God deserves that level of reverence, if Jeuss said do not call any man on earth your Father then you know kneeling for flesh and blood is a sin

I think it’s worth noting that the major question here is intention. When we kneel before God, we intend to bring ourselves before him as is proper to his nature as our creator. However, this does not mean that kneeling in and of itself necessitates the same attitude. If I kneel under my sink to fix the pipes, I’m not worshipping the sink. Same thing goes for your girlfriend.

@NigelJ if I had to guess, the significance of kneeling in proposal is the giving of the man to the woman. While the man is the head of the woman, he is still called to love her and Christ loves the church. And since Christ gives himself for the church, man gives himself for woman. This is a compatibilist framework.

Marriage proposal customs vary from one country/society to another.  Here is the West, the tradition of a man getting down on one knee to propose marriage to his beloved is fairly recent.  It originates from the Middle Ages in Western Europe when a knight would drop to one knee as a sign of respect to royalty.  Even ordinary subjects would demonstrate their respect and loyalty to their king, or feudal lord or persons of nobility, by going down on one knee and bowing their head.  This act is not the same as worship.

While kneeling is considered a traditional style of proposing, there is little consensus on its historical origins, and it in fact appears to be a fairly modern custom. Connections have been made to kneeling in European feudal society, in which kneeling before a lord suggested servitude and surrender. Medieval imagery sometimes depicted a knight kneeling before a lady in an act of courtly love, suggesting kneeling as a form of romantic expression was similar to the submission given to lords. Kneeling during a marriage proposal has been suggested as a similar form of submission.
Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kneeling#Proposals

Matthew Henry (died 1714) made these astute observations about the relationship between men and women:

Woman was not made out of Adam's head to rule over him, nor out of his feet to be trampled upon by him, but out of his side to be equal with him, under his arm to be protected by him, and near his heart to be loved by him.


Eve's being made after Adam, and out of him, puts an honour upon that sex, as the glory of the man, 1 Cor. 11:7.  If man is the head, she is the crown, a crown to her husband, the crown of the visible creation.

This is a matter of conscience.  Christian men do not worship their wives although they might adore them.  Going down on one bended knee to ask for the hand of a lady in marriage seems less like an act of worship than it does an act of respect. Falling down prostrate would be something entirely different, and unwarranted!
Post Script: When a man gets down on one knee and asks the woman he loves if she would do him the honour of becoming his wife, he is showing respect and humility. He isn't making assumptions or taking anything for granted. Neither is he worshipping her.
The only reason the man who is now my husband was excused from not getting down on one knee to propose to me is that we were outside on a very cold January morning and there was snow on the ground.

"Christian men do not worship their wives although they might adore them." It would be great if you could add the proper meaning of "With this ring I thee wed; this gold and silver I thee give, with my body I thee worship and with all my worldly goods I thee endow" from the Book of Common Prayer.  Or do you think I should ask a separate question?  There is a hint for the answer here.

@GratefulDisciple - Excellent observation. Fortunately I do not follow the Book of Common Prayer and when I was wed, my husband was not obliged to assent to worshiping me. Also, I wasn't asked to obey him, much to his regret (-:

@GratefulDisciple - I note the distinction being made between the worship of God (latria) and the worship of the husband to his wife. Interesting article.
